# ASP.NET MVC 5 Actionlink ignores actionname

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: Txt.Get("rsTerugNaarOverzicht"),
                 actionName: "Index",
                 controllerName: "OfferteOverzicht", 
                 routeValues: new { is10Days = true, maand = Model.OverzichtMaand, jaar = Model.OverzichtJaar }, 
                 htmlAttributes: new { @class = "wijzigen" })
```

is rendered as:

```
<a class="wijzigen" href="/OfferteOverzicht?is10Days=True&maand=3&jaar=2021">Terug naar overzicht</a>
```

I was expecting this:

```
<a class="wijzigen" href="/OfferteOverzicht/Index?is10Days=True&maand=3&jaar=2021">Terug naar overzicht</a>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's most likely ignored, because `Index` is the default action on that controller. Try referencing some other, non-default action - is the action name ignored in that case, too?

Comment: Apparently it was caused bij a route:
      routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Root",
        url: "{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
      );

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );    Removed the first one and the problem was gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it.
It was caused by an entry in the routeconfig:

```
   routes.MapRoute( 
    name: "Root",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
   );

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

I needed to remove the first one.

Now, eventhough not visible in the link, the action is called and executed.